# Google Map Error message in IE

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Tab containing google map and other informations about the location.
If I switch between the Tabs then in IE i have always a Javascript Error message

> "Invalid Argument at line 30"

If i remove the Map from the Tab then I don't get this error message.

I have tried some solutions like

setting style for the DIV contain googlemap like

```
"visibility:hidden;height:0px"
```

or

```
"position:absolute;left:-5000px"
```

but i patch this error.

Any suggestion?

Comment: And what is the "line 30" exactly ? Some of your code or from the API from Google ?

Comment: Yes, this is in google API main.js file.

Comment: Without seeing your code and how you use the API, it is pretty difficult to help you. Does this happen in other browsers than IE? Is the Tabs made with jQuery or by yourself ? Check this **[other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432096/trouble-with-invalid-argument-when-switching-jqueryui-based-tabs)** to see if it helps.

Comment: it is only in IE and its a know problem of IE. Hiding a DIV contents that contains google map or Removing Div's contents with google map will produce this error irrespective of how the DOM is created.